# How can I point a delegate to a method obtained with reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, delegates

I dynamically load an assembly as:

```
 var assembly = Assembly.LoadFile("PathOFMyDll");
```

anyways that assembly has the static method `Filter` inside the class `DynamicClass`. So once I have that assembly I exececute that method as:

```
 var filter = assembly.GetType("DyamicClass").GetMethod("Filter");

 // that method accepts a object as parameter
 filter.Invoke(null, new object[] { "test" });
```

---

**Now my question is:**

I have the delegate `delegate bool FilterDelegate(object item);` why it is not possible make a delegate of that type point to that method in order to have:

```
 FilterDelegate myPointerToMethodFilter = (FilterDelegate)assembly.GetType("DyamicClass").GetMethod("Filter");
 bool result = myPointerToMethodFilter("test");
```

note the compiler only complains when trying to compile. I do not get any syntax errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to create a delegate from a `MethodInfo` object, but casting is not sufficient.

Instead, use [`Delegate.CreateDelegate()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53cz7sc6.aspx):

```
MethodInfo myMethodFilter = assembly.GetType("DyamicClass").GetMethod("Filter");
FilterDelegate myPointerToMethodFilter = (FilterDelegate)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof (FilterDelegate), myMethodFilter);
```